# SP Executed Successfully But Data Not Updated

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, telerik-mvc, telerik-open-access

I am using **Telerik Open Access** for interaction with **MSSQL SERVER 2012**.

I have made a stored procedure which will set `IsActive` column of `Role` Table to 0(false) and return all data of `Role` where `IsActive= 1` (True)

My `Role` table has columns:

`RoleId(int)`, `RoleName(varchar(50))`, `AliasName(varchar(50))`, `IsActive(bit)`.

My Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [SPDeleteRole]
@Role_Id int
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE [Role] SET IsActive = 0 WHERE RoleId = @Role_Id
  Select * from [Role] WHERE IsActive = 1 ORDER BY RoleName
END
```

I call this SP in my application like below:

```
public List<RoleDTO> DeleteRole(int roleId)
{
  OAParameter oaParameter = new OAParameter();
  oaParameter.ParameterName = "Role_Id";
  oaParameter.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;
  oaParameter.Value = roleId;
  List<RoleDTO> roleList = base.ExecWithStoreProcedureGetDataWithParam("SPDeleteRole", oaParameter);
  return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<RoleDTO>>(roleList);
}

public List<T> ExecWithStoreProcedureGetDataWithParam(string query, OAParameter parameters)
{
  var queryResult = dbContext.ExecuteQuery<T>(query, CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters);
  dbContext.Dispose();
  return queryResult.ToList();
}
```

Now my problem is this works fine. But when I refresh the page, the role which I inactivated comes to in the list.

I checked through debugging that list comes from SP is exactly of Active Roles. But as soon as I refresh the page the role inactivated roles comes again in the list. I have verified SP by executing it in MSSQL SERVER and it works fine.

**Issue:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you should write `dbContext.SaveChanges()` before you dispose the dbcontext?

Comment: This should be the cause. OpenAccessContext.Dispose() will rollback automatically any pending transactions and the call to the stored procedure will start one (if it is not already started) and it needs explicit context.SaveChanges() to commit the transaction.